# Eclipse JSTL Core Autocomplete

Tags: eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

Eclipse's auto-complete for JSP tags works with Spring Security tags, but not JSTL core.

I've got the following declarations at the top of the JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

I'm depending on JSTL:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

...But curiously, JSTL Core never auto-suggests.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks, you can tell how awake I am today!

Comment: What file extension are you using for your JSP files?

Comment: I'm using `.jsp`, and even added the file via Eclipse's fancy Create New JSP pseudo-wizardy thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that the `jstl-api.jar` that likely comes with the `javax.servlet>jstl` depencency does not contain the `TLD` files in the `META-INF`. What you need is the `jstl-impl.jar` file to be available somewhere on the project classpath (Maven dependencies or just included directly) because in the `jstl-impl.jar` file you can see it has this file: `META-INF/c.tld`

If the Eclipse JSP editor can read the `jstl-impl.jar` from your project classpath, then it can read in the tag info and give you auto-complete.

[image: Screenshot of jstl completion in Eclipse JSP editor]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jboss or other servers try jstl-api.jar. Add it to the eclipse classpath and it should work like charm.

Comment: Can you please add an example of the classpath change?

Comment: Click on the java project in eclipse -> Right click - > Properties -> Java Build Path - > Add jstl.jar to the libraries tab and rebuild the project